# Vertical alignment of tikzpicture pgf plot graphs in minipage environment with subcaptions

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, vertical-alignment, minipage

I want to have these two graphs created with `pgfplots` aligned vertically, while the subcaption stay aligned (thats why the option `[t]` is used in the `minipage` environment). Their boxes seem to be of different sizes. How could I do this?

code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,oneside]{report}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{a4wide} 
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepgfplotslibrary{units}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[!h]
\centering
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\textwidth}
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale = 0.9]
    \begin{axis}[use units,
    xlabel=N,
    ylabel=w\textsubscript{fm}/w\textsubscript{fn},
    grid=major,
    legend style={draw=none,at={(0.77,0.25)},anchor=north,legend columns=1,column sep=5pt},
    legend cell align={left},
    ]
    \addplot+[black,mark=square*, only marks,mark size=0.7pt, mark options={scale=2,solid}] table [x=n, y=w_n, /pgf/number format/read comma as period, col sep=semicolon]{lab-seal-geometry-study.CSV};
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    (a) Subcaption
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\textwidth}
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale = 0.9]
    \begin{axis}[use units,
    x unit=mm, xlabel=C,
    ylabel=w\textsubscript{fm}/w\textsubscript{fn},
    grid=major,
    legend style={draw=none,at={(0.77,0.25)},anchor=north,legend columns=1,column sep=5pt},
    legend cell align={left},
    ]
    \addplot+[black,mark=square*, only marks,mark size=0.7pt, mark options={scale=2,solid}] table [x=c, y=w_c, /pgf/number format/read comma as period, col sep=semicolon]{lab-seal-geometry-study.CSV};

    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    (b) Subcaption
\end{minipage}
\caption{Caption}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quick hack could be to add `\strut` to each of the `xlabel`s, e.g. `xlabel=C\strut`. That way both of them have the same height, so the alignment is better.

Have you considered the `subcaption` package and its `subfigure` environment by the way? The syntax of the environment is the same as for `minipage`, so you only need to change `minipage` to `subfigure` in your code. Then you can use `\caption{Subcaption}` instead of `(a) Subcaption`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,oneside]{report}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
%\usepackage{a4wide} % deprecated
\usepackage{geometry} % use geometry instead
\geometry{margin=2cm}

\usepgfplotslibrary{units}
%\usepackage{graphicx} % loaded by tikz, which is loaded by pgfplots

\usepackage{subcaption} % for subfigure env
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[!h]
\centering
\begin{subfigure}[t]{0.5\textwidth}
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
    width=0.95\linewidth, % set width instead of scaling
    use units,
    xlabel=N\strut, % add strut
    ylabel=w\textsubscript{fm}/w\textsubscript{fn},
    grid=major,
    legend style={draw=none,at={(0.77,0.25)},anchor=north,legend columns=1,column sep=5pt},
    legend cell align={left},
    ]
    \addplot+[black,mark=square*, only marks,mark size=0.7pt, mark options={scale=2,solid},domain=10:24] {rnd};%table [x=n, y=w_n, /pgf/number format/read comma as period, col sep=semicolon]{lab-seal-geometry-study.CSV};
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{Subcaption}
\end{subfigure}%
\begin{subfigure}[t]{0.5\textwidth}
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
    width=0.95\linewidth, % set width instead of scaling
    use units,
    x unit=mm, xlabel=C\strut, % add \strut here as well
    ylabel=w\textsubscript{fm}/w\textsubscript{fn},
    grid=major,
    legend style={draw=none,at={(0.77,0.25)},anchor=north,legend columns=1,column sep=5pt},
    legend cell align={left},
    ]
    \addplot+[black,mark=square*, only marks,mark size=0.7pt, mark options={scale=2,solid},domain=1:4] {rnd};% table [x=c, y=w_c, /pgf/number format/read comma as period, col sep=semicolon]{lab-seal-geometry-study.CSV};
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{Subcaption}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{Caption}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```